# Trying to build a file in PHP and use fwrite to file

Tags: php, fwrite

trying to figure out how i can make a and save a file while including default info from another file. i tried include but it did not work. any suggestion on how to build this file?

```
<?php
$wrtID = $_POST["fileID"];

SQL statement here to get relevant info

mkdir("CNC/$wrtID", 0770, true);

?>
<?php

$batfile = fopen("CNC/$wrtID/$wrtID.bat", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO **** Run NC-Generator WOODWOP 4.0 ****
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-sl.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-sr.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-tb.mpr
NCWEEKE.exe -n=C:/WW4/$wrtID/$wrtID-dc.mpr
@ECHO **** Done ****
";
fwrite($batfile, $txt);
fclose($batfile);
?>

<?php
$slfile = fopen("CNC/$wrtID/$wrtID-sl.mpr", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "

include("defaultcnc.php");

if ( additional file pats needed ) {
    include("component-1.php");
}

";

fwrite($slfile, $txt);
fclose($slfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem in the first block of code.

On the second block, the interpreter will consider the second double quotes to mean the end of the string `$txt = " include("`. So everything after that would produce a PHP error.

But even if you escape those the mpr file will have the string `include("defaultcnc,php");` but not the actual contents of that file. For that you should do `file_get_contents("defaultcnc.php")`.

something like:

```
<?php
$slfile = fopen("CNC/$wrtID/$wrtID-sl.mpr", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
// set params to pass to defaultcnc.php
$value1 = 1;
$value2 = "I'm a text string";
$file = urlencode("defaultcnc.php?key1=".$value1."&key2=".$value2);
$txt = file_get_contents($file);

if ( additional file pats needed ) {
    $txt .= file_get_contents("component-1.php");
}

fwrite($slfile, $txt);
fclose($slfile);
?>
```

I assume `additional file pats needed` means something to you. It should be a condition evaluating either true or false.

Comment: I will give this a try. yes the if statement will have a true,false if the additional components are needed with the new file. will there be a problem if the default file contains a lot of " "?

Comment: I don't think there is any problem, from the PHP side, if the file has a lot of spaces. I don't know what an mpr file is, so no idea from that side.

Comment: This worked great only problem i need to insert a few variables into the default file before writing to file. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are many. The simplest may be adding them as a querystring `file_get_contents("defaultcnc.php?key1=value1&key2=value2")`. If the values contain spaces you should urlencode the string before doing the file_get_contents. Updated the answer.

Comment: For some reason when i add the querystring the file that is written is blank and without the querystring it works.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the full URL. If that doesn't solve it you can try using SESSION variables.

Comment: Thanks i will try these. Will the php code of the default.php file be run before being written to the file?

Comment: @heykarch If you use the full url (http) yes, because it goes through your web server, who can execute the PHP code. If you use local paths then no, because it just accesses the file system.

Comment: that did the trick with full http url with the string variables i was able to create the new file.